Buoyancy basics


I was solving this question and in the solution, they have applied a buoyant force exerted by kerosene. It makes sense by the basic definition of the buoyant force from Archimedes principle. However, it does not make sense if we look at the points of pressure differences in the vertical direction. Is there some way we can intuitively prove that buoyant force by the kerosene is acting on the block.

The result is correct, and is in intuitive agreement with the "bouyant force = weight of fluid displaced" viewpoint, so what is it do you want?

@naturallyInconsistent When we find the formula for buoyant force we use the fact that the pressure difference creates an upward force in the vertical direction but the kerosene here can only exert pressure difference forces in the horizontal direction, why actually is it applying a buoyant force? I thought because the horizontal force provide a torque of dgb*h^2/6 at height h/3, that might be the reason but then i got a different formula for the buoyant force and also the net torques still cancel out.

@naturallyInconsistent Yes, I agree with his explanation and also that buoyant force is always vertical but I only had a problem with it because from Archimedes principle it makes sense. Though it does not tell us how to derive the formula for buoyant force and we derive it by marking the pressure points in the vertical direction. The kerosene does not have any pressure points at all in the vertical direction and that was my doubt, even tho it does not have any pressure differences in the vertical direction how can it be applying a buoyant force?

The intuitive way to think about these types of buoyancy problems is in terms of the pressure due the heads of the fluids.
Starting with the stated set up, the pressure under the ice cube due to the downward force of gravity on the ice cube is equal to the weight of the ice (volume ($V_i$) $\times$ density($p_i$) $\times g$, distributed across the area of the base of the cube. This gives us
$P_i = V_i p_i g /A_i = (h_i \times A_i) p_i g /A_i = h_i A_i p_i.$
Notice that the area term cancels out and we can basically ignore the area and think of the forces only in terms of height and density.

In the above diagram I have added an imaginary reference level ($h_0$) that is always level with the base of the floating object. I have also drawn the diagram more to scale, because as the answer reveals $h_k = h_w$. An important intuitive concept is the pressure along this horizontal reference line is always equal everywhere along it, because if it was not the fluid would move sideways due the pressure differential to equalise things.
For example, imagine we temporarily hold the ice cube stationary while we carefully siphon off the kerosene layer. As we siphon off the kerosene, the total mass of fluid at the side, above the base line $h_0$ is reduced and the pressure at that level reduces. When the ice cube is released, water now flows from underneath the cube to the region of reduced pressure at the side, and as it does so the cube sinks further into the water as the water is displaced until a new equilibrium is reached, as illustrate below:

Without doing any calculations it is well known that about 90% of a floating ice block is below the water level. Now 10% of the block is above the liquid surface, so it is clear that previously the kerosene layer was reducing the buoyancy of the ice block.  Just to be clear, when I said the ice block sinks further into the water layer, I should make it clear that I am talking relative to the water layer only. Previously only 50% of the ice was below the water layer and now 90% is below the water layer. In that sense the ice has sunk relative to the water but at the same time it has risen relative to the surface of the combined liquids.

Is there some way we can intuitively prove that buoyant force by the
kerosene is acting on the block.

While my answer is not a definitive proof, I hope I have demonstrated in an intuitive way, that the kerosene layer does influence the buoyancy of the ice cube. The presence of a kerosene layer effectively reduces the average density of the fluid the the ice block is floating in, so the ice block floats lower relative to the surface.

Divide the world into 3 parts. 1) The ice cube, 2) the fluid, and 3) enough fluid to fill the hole if the ice cube was not there.
If you only had 1) or 3), they would fall down because of their weight.
If you had 2) and 3), 2) would hold 3). The surface of the hole exerts an upward force equal to the weight of 3).
If you had 1) and 3), 1) will sink until it makes a big enough hole to get an upward force equal to the weight of 1). This is the weight of 3).
If you think about these weights, you can solve the problem in an intuitive way.
